# C - Runtime Error using char str() function

Tags: c, function, char, runtime

I have a global variable, character.

```
char character[1];
char str(){
    if (strcmp(character,"N")) {
        return 'N';
    }else if (strcmp(character,"S")) {
        return 'S';
    }else if (strcmp(character,"E")) {
        return 'E';
    }else if (strcmp(character,"W")) {
        return 'W';
    }else if (strcmp(character,"Q")) {
        return 'Q';
    }else if (!((strcmp(character,"N"))||(strcmp(character,"S"))||(strcmp(character,"E"))||(strcmp(character,"W"))||(strcmp(character,"Q")))) {
        return '!';
    }
}
```

This function compiled fine but when I use in the int main() function the program crashes because of some runtime error. IE:

```
scanf("%s", character);
printf("%s", str()); //crashes here
```

----- or even -----

```
scanf("%s", character);
char *str_ptr = str(); //crashes here
printf("%p", *str_ptr );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the strcmp function compares two strings.

therefore, both parameters must be NUL terminated strings.

char character[1]  has no room for both a character and NUL terminator.

the code is actually only comparing a single char from a global variable against literal characters.

suggest

```
if( 'N' == character[0] ) return 'N';
....
// used when character[0] does not match any of the above comparisons.
return '!';
```

note: one 'if' statement for each character of interest, 
followed by the return '!';

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` format specifier expects a null terminated string as parameter.
Use `%c` instead to print a single character.

```
char *str_ptr = str();
```

results in an compiler error since you cannot cast a `char` int a `char *`.

And btw you can compare two characters by using the == operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your scanf/printf format codes are wrong.  You have prototyped the function as char (not char*).  Try using %c instead of %s.  Also remember that a char and a char* are very different things, one is a storage location for a single character, the other is a pointer to a location for one or more characters.